# affine independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I, somewhat informally, state that d+1 points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are affinely independent, if they don't lie in a $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Affine* subspace, yes. (That's a translation of an ordinary vector subspace.)

Comment: ah true, because it doesnt need to contain the origin, right?

Comment: @stefan, yes, exactly.